# SQL select non-overlapping ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, range, postgresql-9.4, overlapping

I have a table with the following columns: range_from and range_to.
I need to select non-overlapping ranges in a query, using PostgreSQL9.4.

For example, let's say this is my data:

```
range_from     range_to
1              5
2              5
3              5
4              7
6              10
```

Non-overlapping ranges (starting with the first one) would be:

```
1      5
6      10
```

I tried using lead/lag, but that didn't get me anywhere since every two consecutive ranges do overlap, but [1, 5] and [6, 10] don't.

Here is that test data in a test table:

```
create table test_table(id integer, range_from integer, range_to integer);
insert into test_table (id, range_from, range_to) values (1, 1, 5), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 5), (4, 4, 7), (5, 6, 10);
```

I'm not getting anywhere with this and I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: What about the ranges [2, 5] and [6, 10]?  Should that be in the result set or not (and if not, why not)?  They are also non-overlapping ranges. You need to specify the problem criteria a bit more explicitly.

Comment: No. I want to start with the first range and then add ranges which don't overlap. So, I start with [1, 5], then skip [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 7] because they overlap, then add [6, 10], and so on.
But if it makes things easier, *any* subset of non-overlapping ranges could work - that means that [2, 5] and [6, 10] would be one of the solutions.

Comment: Probably `plpgsql` is the simplest and most convenient solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this needs to be done in a query.

Comment: So it is the job for [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/): http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=3c36bd84ca23ec7c27e97d9e14522a2a

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly!